# Can an elasticsearch child have two or more parents?

Tags: elasticsearch, parent-child

Assume this simple relationship:

```
    Parent 1   Parent 2
          \    /
           \  / 
            \/
          Child
```

Is there a way I can specify *two* or more parents in elasticsearch when I index this child? According to what I'm seeing in the [docs](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/indexing-parent-child.html), the `PUT` command in elasticsearch only allows for one parent (e.g., /children?parent=parent1).

Comment: this is gonna sound dumb but could you combine nesting and parent-child? lol

Comment: Is there a way to have two children?